# Which one to use, Visual Studio Installer or Inno Setup?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, inno-setup

I asked some questions about Inno Setup and .NET Framework installation. Now I am thinking whether is it better to use Visual Studio Installer or Inno Setup?

Which of the two do you think is better and more functional  for this type of problem, and in general which is better to use for installer creation?

Comment: It might help prevent a flood of purely subjective, "I prefer x" answers if you edit your question to provide some more details on your particular application and any specialized tasks that you need to perform during the setup process.

Comment: Disregarding of what other answers are, you should be aware that VS setup project was retired by Microsoft, and this is obviously not a good choice for long-term project...

Comment: Hmm, somebody needs to tell the crew that worked on VS2010.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, Inno Setup is easier and more reliable, but if you must ship an MSI, use Visual Studio.  See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/dotnetfx_innosetup_instal.aspx) for installing .NET with Inno.

Comment: In support of this answer - I used Inno to distribute a specialized Windows toolkit (multiple DLLs and EXEs to multiple folders, multiple configurations, custom screens, custom post-install actions) for about 10 years, with a customer base that ended up numbering ~2000. In that time, I had _no_ (zero) installation problems: none on my part, none reported by customers.  If you're like me, you've personally experienced horrible behavior by MSIs created _by Microsoft_. My 'favorite' is the MSI that fails reporting only a _hex error code_ that Google can't find.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Installer is retiring in 2010 so for future use it is not suitable. Also there is a tool called InstallShied Limited Edition in VS 2010 for creating installers (based on some other technology).

If you want to create installers directly in Visual Studio try this extension called **Visual & Installer**: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5e57fe9a-ae5d-4740-a1c3-7a8e278e105b

It supports Inno Setup and NSIS (Nullsoft Installer, both are free and open sourced) and VS 2012 and VS 2012 are already supported so it looks fine.

Comment: The Visual & Installer plugin is trial.

Comment: For those who need it: You can continue using the VS 2010 installer projects in VS 2013 with the following extension: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d